# Please explain the code in this count sort

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I was learning count sort from tutorial and my C++ source code is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void countSort(int arr[], int size)
{
    //declare output array
    int output[size];
    //declare count array
    int count[size];
    //initialize count[] with zero
    //memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num )
    memset(count, 0, sizeof(count));

    //input array element is the index of count array
    //storing the repetition/frequency
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        count[arr[i]]++;
    }


    /*
        Modify the count array such that each element at 
        each index stores the sum of previous counts.
    */
    // i=1 because, previous is 0 due to avoid -1
    for(int i=1; i<size; i++){
        count[i] += count[i-1];
    }

    //Build ouput array
    //count array element is the index of output array 
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        //***********THIS LINE***********
        output[count[arr[i]]-1] = arr[i];
        count[arr[i]]--;
    }

    //copy ouput array into input array arr[]
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            arr[i] = output[i];
    }

}

void printArray(int arr[], int size){
    // Ascending order
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }   
    cout<<endl;

}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int arr[] = {1,4,1,2,7,5,2,6,6,9};
    int size= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    countSort(arr, size);
    printArray(arr, size);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand about taking sorted array in output array.However why we need to decrements  the output index by -1:

```
output[count[arr[i]]-1] = arr[i];
```

I didn't understand this part. I try with only `output[count[arr[i]]]` but it doesn't gave me the correct sorted array.

Comment: Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms for the explanation and proof of correctness of  `counting sort`.

Comment: I updated my answer to show an example where count[] is converted into starting indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array of counts was converted in to an array of ending indices, point one past the end of each logical bucket, so 1 is subtracted from each index. This could be combined to use pre-decrement, and the array scanned backwards:

```
    for(i=size; i; ){
        i--;
        output[--count[arr[i]]] = arr[i];
    }
```

Getting back to the counts after they are summed up, note that count[0] contains a count of all the elements equal to zero, and count[1] contains a count of all elements == zero and all elements == 1, and so on, so count[0] is the logical size of the bucket that will contain the zeroes, and the size is 1 greater than the index to the last element. The same logic applies to count[1] and so on.

Example code where the counts are converted into starting indices. output[] converted to use new (to avoid stack overflow and some compilers don't support variable length arrays). count[10] assumes the range of numbers is limited to 0 through 9.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void countSort(int arr[], int size)
{
    //declare output array
    int * output = new int[size];
    //declare count array
    // assumes range of values is 0 to 9
    int count[10];
    //initialize count[] with zero
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        count[i] = 0;
    //input array element is the index of count array
    //storing the repetition/frequency
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        count[arr[i]]++;
    }
    // convert counts into starting indices (this is the main change)
    int sum = 0, tmp;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        tmp = count[i];
        count[i] = sum;
        sum += tmp;
    }
    //Build ouput array
    //count array element is the index of output array 
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        output[count[arr[i]]++] = arr[i];
    }
    //copy ouput array into input array arr[]
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            arr[i] = output[i];
    }
    delete[] output;
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size){
    // Ascending order
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }   
    cout<<endl;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,4,1,2,7,5,2,6,6,9};
    int size= sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    countSort(arr, size);
    printArray(arr, size);
    return 0;
}
```